# PHP xdebug is loaded, but never connects and never logs anything

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying to get xdebug to talk to PHPStorm from inside a docker container.

My .ini file currently looks like this, but believe me: I've experimented with many combinations of these settings this morning:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote.enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_host=10.0.14.79
xdebug.remote_port=2050
xdebug.idekey=mediabank
xdebug.scream=1
xdebug.auto_trace=1
xdebug.trace_output_dir=/tmp/
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

Every single one of these settings I can confirm they're set, with variations of `php -i |grep <NAME_SETTING_HERE>`, or with `phpinfo();` . And yet, when I try to run a PHP script, PHPStorm sits there like nothing has happened, and my xdebug.log remains resolutely empty. Nothing! Just to be certain, I've tried :

```
echo '' >/tmp/xdebug.log
chmod 777 /tmp/xdebug.log
```

No change.

I've run through everything I can find here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#

And as a last resort, a reboot of my host machine. No progress.

Does anyone have any more suggestions for me? Or does the painful hell of `var_dump();` await me?

EDIT: Added a sample cli file on request.

```
<?php

echo ("Running\n");
xdebug_break();
echo ("Still running\n");
die("I'm done\n");
```

Comment: Is your phpstorm set correctly to accept the incoming connection with specified key and port ??

Comment: @alithedeveloper Thanks for the reaction. The answers are "yes", and "yes". Also "Break at first line in scripts" is on and the listener is on. But even if I hadn't set all of this, I would expect something to turn up in the logs.

Comment: And I've tried out a whole range of `remote_ports`. No luck there!

Comment: Ok , can you run `ipconfig getifaddr en0` on your terminal and replace `xdebug.remote_host=10.0.14.79` ip with whatever you get from command above. assuming you are on mac . Thats how i get it up and running

Comment: On some OSses, `/tmp` isn't really `/tmp`. Instead they use some private temp stuff, and you'd find your log file in `/tmp/systemd-private-9301532e5ff749e388f365a25f51e9ea-httpd.service-HRR15v/`

Comment: `$ ipconfig getifaddr en0`  says `10.0.14.79`  :-(

Comment: @Derick Thanks, but that doesn't seem to be the case in my docker container. Also, I've tried various locations under the webroot too

Comment: have you set a debug cookie? https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/

Comment: @abdusco Thanks! I'm really wanting to debug a cli script. I think the issue is more fundamental than a browser cookie :-(

Comment: @BenHillier please add the information about the CLI script to your question - it's important to know that you are not talking about debugging something from a HTTP call

Comment: Try turning off your firewall

Comment: In my setup, I have to use the IP `172.17.0.1` which is assigned to the interface `docker0` - I don't have `en0` on my system

Comment: @NicoHaase I've added an example cli file to the question.

Comment: Any explanation for the downvotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not actually enable Xdebug:

`xdebug.remote.enable=1`

There should not be a `.` in between `remote` and `enable`, instead it should be a `_`.

Comment: Yes it is enabled if you look at the settings

Comment: Go check that again, because the lines from `php.ini` that you posted won't enable Xdebug. There needs to be a `_` in between `remote` and `enable`, not a `.`.

Comment: I think both variations should work, but running `php -i |grep remote` confirms it's on, as does `phpinfo()`.

Comment: nope derek is right. my bad. it does need to be `remote_enable`

Comment: I stand corrected! Once I changed this flag, in combination with choosing yet another port to debug on, then it worked. You're a life-saver mate!

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's help you:

docker-compose.yml

```
wordpress:
        build: docker/php-fpm
        volumes:
            - .:${PROJECT_FILES}
            - ${DOCKER_DIR}data/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
            - ${DOCKER_DIR}data/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
        depends_on:
            - db
        environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            - 9000:9000
```

in xdebug.ini

```
[xdebug]
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_startup_errors = On
display_errors = On
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
```

Checked it's working.

Comment: The core of this post is that I should be mounting my ini files in the correct place, I think. That's been done. `php --ini` shows me the correct ini file is loaded. Also, I can see all the changes I make in that ini file immediately

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Which of these lines is needed? Why should one add environment variables for Wordpress if something concerning XDebug is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i set up my xdebug.ini ( variables are injected from an environment file while runing `docker-compose up -d`)

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=${PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_ENABLE}
xdebug.remote_handler=${PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_HANDLER}
xdebug.remote_port=${PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_PORT}
xdebug.remote_autostart=${PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_AUTOSTART}
xdebug.remote_connect_back=${PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_CONNECT_BACK}
xdebug.idekey=${PHP_XDEBUG_IDEKEY}
xdebug.remote_host=${PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. What do all these environment variable stand for? And which of these solves the problem?

Comment: These variables mean the xdebug settings within the context of conversation and question ????

Comment: So, you just assign some variables to other variables. What exactly does this solve? Which of these variables is needed for which case? And why not store the values of these variables directly in there?

Answer (score 0):

You must set a `XDEBUG_SESSION` cookie before XDebug server triggers a PHPStorm debug session.

See here to generate bookmarklets:
https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/

Or use an extension:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/
- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xdebug-helper-for-firefox/

Comment: Are you sure about this? Isn't that why there is a `remote_autostart` option?

Comment: Thanks! But my CLI scripts also fail to run. This goes a bit deeper than a cookie, I'm afraid. Also, there should at least be something logged.

Comment: Are you using a public docker image that we can use to test locally?

Comment: You indeed don't need the cookie if `remote_autostart` is enabled.